# Improving a LINQ query so that it executes completely in the database

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have an `Address` model (simplified)...

```
public class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

...and a `DbContext` derived class that contains a set of `Addresses`:

```
public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
```

Then I have this query which is supposed to retrieve one or no `address` (`_context` is an instance of my database context class):

```
public Address GetAddress(string city, int addressId)
{
    Address address = null;

    // this is a database query
    var addresses = _context.Addresses.Where(a => a.City == city).ToList();

    // the rest queries in memory
    if (addresses.Count <= 1)
        address = addresses.FirstOrDefault();
    else
    {
        address = addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AddressId == addressId);
        if (address == null)
            address = addresses.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    return address;
}
```

The query is a bit weird. The logic is simply:

- If there is only one (or no) address in the database table with the requested `city` take this address as result.
- If there are multiple addresses with the requested `city` prefer the one that has the given `addressId`. If none of the result addresses has this `addressId` just take the first one.

Disturbing is that the `.ToList()` call potentially loads a lot of addresses into memory I'm not interested in. In the end I filter only one of the loaded addresses in memory as the final result.

Is there a way to rewrite this query (with LINQ-to-Entities) so that it runs completely in the database and returns only one or no address (with a single database roundtrip)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your logic can be interpreted as preferring the address with a given ID and if none matches jut picking any at all. Your query does not enforce any order for that case.

```
var addressesInCity = _context.Addresses.Where(a => a.City == city);
var addrByID = addressesInCity.Where(a => a.AddressId == addressId);
var anyAddr = addressesInCity.Take(1);
```

You can write this with two queries:

```
addrByID.FirstOrDefault() ?? anyAddr.FirstOrDefault();
```

You can combine those into a single query:

```
addrByID.Select(a => new { Priority = 1, a })
.Concat(anyAddr.Select(a => new { Priority = 2, a }))
.OrderBy(x => x.Priority)
.Take(1)
.Select(x => x.a)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

This saves a roundtrip and SQL Server understands the sorting by a constant. It will run efficiently. Not *necessarily* more efficiently than the first form but not significantly worse.

Note, that the order of results returned by `UNION (ALL)` is undefined. We need to enforce order by introducing a `Priority` field.

Comment: Just to note. There are certain versions of EF for which there was a bug on this point.

Comment: EF never stops to disappoint. L2S can do this and it is deprecated for 5 years now while EF is under active development.

Comment: Don't get me started with L2S. It can't even handle `char` or `varchar`. At least they have new versions of EF with patches. Tell me when they last updated L2S.

Comment: Good point, I sometimes run into that :) Still, its query capabilities were really nice. The C# team produced it. They made the language just work.

Comment: +1 This `Priority` constant is a brilliant idea! I believe EF can translate this correctly. I'll test it and come back with the result.

Comment: If it can't translate the constant, make it a non-constant: `a.ID * 0 + 1`. SQL Server hopefully deletes the subtraction. Sometimes we have to hack around bugs in ORMs.

Comment: Perfect! The query works exactly as you've written it - including the constant `Priority` value. Thanks!